# Strange PYTHONPATH problem

Tags: python, import, importerror

I recently updated my python installation to 2.7 (previously 2.5), and I've noticed a strange problem where I cannot import certain modules that I created.  I had no problem before.  Normally, I edit the PYTHONPATH and add the directory I want to import modules.  For some strange reason, I can no longer import.  I checked my path in PYTHONPATH, and it looked correct.

When I display the sys.path in an interpreter, I see the current directory prepended to every PYTHONPATH entry(i.e. 'c:\blah\blah c:\path\to\module')

If I edit the sys.path by appending the directory that I want at the end of the list,everything works fine(i.e. 'c:\path\to\module\').  I never had to do this before.

I'm on Windows 7 on two computers.

Has anyone else had similar trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found the problem.  Somehow I had added the some of the python standard libraries into PYTHONPATH.  Once I removed those, everything works fine.